# Any point in chunking a 1-D dataset

Tags: hdf5

I'm a newcomer to the HDF5 World. My data is composed of a series of 1D datasets. My application needs to read one dataset at a time, and when it reads a dataset, it needs to read the dataset in its entirety.

I have a basic understanding of HDF5 chunking: a chunk is laid out contiguously on the disk and is fetched in one read operation.

I see how chunking will be helpful when you have a multi-dimensional array and you need to frequently access items that are not contiguous. On the other hand, I don't see chunking being useful in my case: dataset is 1-dimensional and will always be read in its entirety.

Is my analysis correct? If not, please help me understand how chunking will help my cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chunking allows you to handle files that are too big to fit into memory so they need to be processed in chunks. This is not something specific to HDF. What HDF offers you is a storing capability in an open source transparent binary format that has some nice features like meta-data etc. If you can read the file into memory at once and are not interested in alternative ways of storing your files then I do not see the necessity to use HDF. However, if you want to store similar files and possibly related results in a hierarchical i.e. folder-like way in one file to improve work flow or if you have files that need to be processed in chunks because they do not fit into memory at once, then HDF might just be what you are looking for.

Comment: Appreciate your response. Nice answer.

Comment: I do not know on which platforms you operate but if you want a nice overview and some examples to play around a good start is the book "Python and HDF5" by Andrew Collette who is also a developer in the HDF group. It is based on Python but gives a lot of info on HDF in general and its intricacies and working.

Comment: I'm already reading through Andrew's book. It's pretty thorough, but it didn't answer this aspect about chunking clearly. It very clearly explains that if you'd be frequently accessing elements of your dataset that are not likely to be contiguous on the disk, then chunking your dataset so these elements are laid out contiguously will improve performance. Chunking as a way to deal with datasets larger than memory isn't discussed in his book.

Comment: Get your point. That is exactly the scenario I'm facing. By transposing a column-wise operation to a chunk-wise row operation I'm trying to handle data that does not fit into memory at once. However, it might even be possible to improve performance if the file fits into memory but you are applying an operation on a large number of non-contiuous variables. I haven't tried this. I'm more or less forced to use chunk-wise operations due to the memory limit.